# Impose constraints on the coefficient matrix of a var model in R

Tags: r, machine-learning

how can I impose constraints on the coefficient matrix of a var model in r. 
Some of my code is followed

```
library(readxl)
dat_pc_log_d <- read_excel("C:/Users/Desktop/dat_pc_log_d.xlsx")
attach(dat_pc_log_d)
dat_pc_log_d$itcrm = NULL
dat_pc_log_d$...1 = NULL

data = ts(dat_pc_log_d,start = c(2004,1),end = c(2019,1),frequency = 4)
VAR_modelo = VAR(data,p=2) 

VAR_modelo_restriccion = restrict(VAR_modelo,method = "ser",thresh = 2.0)
ir_pib = irf(VAR_modelo_restriccion, impulse = "pbipc_log_d", response = c("pbipc_log_d", "expopc_log_d", "pbiagr_log_d"), 
             boot = TRUE, ci = 0.95)
```

I need to ensure exogeneity of a variable, for it I have to impose zero in some lags coefficients of the independent variable. How can I do it ?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(readxl)
dat_pc_log_d <- read_excel("C:/Users//dat_pc_log_d.xlsx")
attach(dat_pc_log_d)


dat_pc_log_d$...1 = NULL

data = ts(dat_pc_log_d,start = c(2004,1),end = c(2019,1),frequency = 4)
VAR_modelo = VAR(data,p=2) 

restriccion = matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                       1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                       1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                       1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                       1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                       1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                       1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                       0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1),
                       nrow=8, ncol=17, byrow = TRUE)

VAR_modelo_restriccion = restrict(VAR_modelo,method = "man", resmat = restriccion)
ir_pib = irf(VAR_modelo_restriccion, impulse = "itcrm", response = c("pbipc_log_d", "expopc_log_d", "inverpc_log_d" , "pbiagr_log_d"), 
             boot = TRUE, nhead=20 ,ci = 0.68)
```